# Given $f(x,y) = 1$, $0<x,y<1$, let $U = X+Y$. Find $f_U(u)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

[image]

Would anyone be able to explain what they did in the second line, especially how they got $0<u<1$, and $1<u<2$

Comment: Quote"..., especially how they got 0." What 0 do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are analyzing the inequality. $y+x\leq u\implies y\leq -x+u$. The blue line represents $y = -x+1$. Notice that $0\leq x,y\leq 0$, so the density is $0$ else where. We only consider the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Also keep in mind, we are dealing with a cube.

1. The case where $0\leq u\leq 1$.  Then one possibility is as follows,
   [image]
   The green line is $y = -x+u$, where $0\leq u\leq 1$
   In other words, we need to integrate the volume "below" the green line.
2. Notice that the sum is at most $2$. That is why the second case is $1< u\leq 2$.  One possibility is as follows.
   [image]
   The green line is $y = -x+u$, where $1< u\leq 2$
   Notice that we are integrating the volume "below" the green line. But we know the entire volume should integrate to $1$. So instead of integrating the lower-left triangle $+$ the trapezoid in between, we instead consider the complement and integrate the triangle above the green line.

Now it should be clear where the bounds on the integral come from. Also, it is easy to check the answer using basic geometry.

Comment: Thank you, Did. That's very kind.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but where did you get y=-x+1 from?

Comment: @HueHue The blue line. The equation for a line is $y = mx+b$. It should be clear (or you can work out) that the slope is $-1$, hence $m = -1$. The y-intercept is $b = 1$.

Comment: Really, why isn't the y intercept u? If you set x =o for y=-x+u isn't the y intercept u?

Comment: @HueHue Yes, that is for the **green** line, not the **blue** line. I was referring to the **blue** line. Otherwise, you are correct.

Comment: Ahh i think I get it, thanks for your patience!!

Comment: @HueHue Don't worry. Good luck!